# 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings' is obsolete

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, class-library

I got the following warning

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings' is obsolete:
>   '"This method is obsolete, it has been replaced by
>   System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings"'

How do you fix it?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Add a reference to the assembly `System.Configuration`.

Then at the top (assuming C#) using System.Configuration (Imports System.Configuration in VB.NET).

Use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"]` to access the settings!

Comment: It was sad how difficult this one was to find an answer to.  I was simply missing the Reference.  THANK YOU @Mike

Comment: Note on GOTCHA -> i had a reference to the assembly but the project had been updated to version 4 and the reference was still using the old version.  I needed to explicitly add the reference.

Comment: Why would Microsoft make obsolete something that worked 'out of the box' with something that requires you to add a reference to an assembly?

Comment: In .NET Core 5.0, `System.Configuration` doesn't exist. :(

Comment: @JesseChisholm I believe there is a nuget with it though

Answer (score 32):

as its a warning i dont think it matters unless you have turned off a treat warnings as errors setting

add a reference to System.Configuration

all you have to do is to update to the latest code so where you used `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[""] change to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""]`

and this should work

Comment: ConfigurationManager - does not exist, where is it?

Comment: add a reference to system.Configuration and then it will work - ill update my answer for this

Comment: configurationManager could not be found even after adding ref :-(

Comment: @yoosafinpace if you are using `ConfigurationManager` in Control Library or out of the project. It will throws the error.

Answer (score 20):

Just in case someone else was looking for the **Add Reference** option to achieve the accepted answer in **Visual Studio 2010**. (I had to do this in updating a VB project).

In Visual Studio 2010:

1. Click on Project > **Add Reference**.
2. Click on the C# tab (even though mine was a pure VB project)
3. Scroll down halfway to find **System.Configuration** (I had v4 since .NET Framework 4.0 was the chosen version)
4. Click OK, then update the line of code as per the suggestion given.

From System.Configuration.Configuration**Settings**.AppSettings("name") 
to System.Configuration.Configuration**Manager**.AppSettings

Without adding the reference IntelliSense won't suggest ConfigurationManager when you type it, and that's because it doesn't have a reference to be aware of where it is. Which is also why you will get errors when you updated the line of code according to their suggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much ~ Guy from the future

Comment: Thank you sir! You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

the System.configuration DLL
exsit in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\

Answer (score 2):

Just replace
`System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings`
with
`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`
in your code.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the reference `using System.Configuration;` at the top of the class. Still the same warning remains.

**In Code Behind:**

Instead of `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]`

Use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]`

By Default the System.configuration Dll will be added in your project.

**In Web.config or App.config:**

```
 <add key="ConnectionString" value="Some Connection Strings or Specific Path"/>
```

Comment: Uh, isn't that exactly what he accepted answer (from 2010) says?

Comment: yes., just check it. still the warning remains the same. I have checked VS2010 and VS2012. @Christian.K

Comment: @RJK just check the answer he accepted. The answer specifically says "Use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"] to access the settings!" I have checked in Chrome and IE 9.

Answer (score 1):

to use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""]` Add Reference Assemblies not use `using System.Configuration;`

Answer (score 1):

you must add reference of System.onfiguration in  your project then add "Using System.onfiguration;"

next step using like this:

```
private string SQLConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQlConnectionString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

example:

replace

```
string smtpServer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailServer"];
```

with

```
string smtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailServer"];
```

also make sure on the top of the case you add:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as mentioned above, just add a reference "System.Configuration" for the application, and within the code you can add "using System.Configuration" to the top of the code and use "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""]" where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I also face same issue, sometimes the assembly reference not loaded properly or if you are using multiple projects it give problems sometimes. You just add reference to assembly. Right Click>Add Reference>.Net>System.configuration> Click OK
You can see now there are many configuration options available choose ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["Con"].ToString();

Build and Smile :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a C# project and I fixed it by writing appSettings instead of AppSettings in the XML file (camelCase expected) in the tag

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="myKey" value="my Value"/>
<appSettings>
```

After all C# is case sensitive