# XML file configuration for c#

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

i have simple problem:
i added reference:

**System.Configuration**

and two using names:

- System.Configuration;
- System.Collection.Specialized;

it's my *App1.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyKey" value="MyValue"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name ="MyHost"
         providerName="System.Data.Sql"
         connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;
                           Integrated Security = true; User ID=Admin;Password=P@ssw0rd;
                           Connection Timeout=2;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and when i would connect to my database, all is OK! (by this way):

```
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
            if(settings != null)
                MessageBox.Show(settings[0].ConnectionString, "ConnectionString");
```

but when i would get value for property MyKey, then string's null, looks like:

```
string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"];
```

what i do wrong?

EDIT:
it's debug view:[image]

Comment: When you put a breakpoint there and look at `AppSettings`, what's inside?

Comment: Are you sure you're running both code samples in the same project?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin yes, i have only one project in this solution.

Comment: Can't reproduce - everything's working fine. Do you do something with your config elsewhere?

Comment: no, i additionally rebuild app, but it didn't give any progress.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. Have you tried removing App.Config and adding it again?

Comment: I know it's [obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959605/system-configuration-configurationsettings-appsettings-is-obsolete), but try using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings`

Comment: solved...I can't have filename: App1.config, only App.config. Thanks you for help guys!

Comment: I guess this wasn't true than: "it's my App.config:".

Comment: Yes, again: sorry, but i'm learning VS and i can't look at all details, i didn't know, that it's important(filename)

Answer (score 0):

I can't have fileName for configuration *App1.config*, only *App.config* is accept.

Comment: The real reason for this is because when you compile your application, it renames `App.config` into `<name of project>.exe.config`. So if you have a file that is anything different than `App.config`, visual studio won't know what to transform.

Comment: Good question. You might have had a loose file somewhere. But there is not enough info to figure that out. If it's really a problem, post another question.

Comment: @W92 hmmm.. your profile pic is misleading. i thought there is a housefly in my monitor... even tried to touch with my hand to move it away....